# Handle Shake Gestures when UIAlertView is displaying

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, screenshot, shake

I want to take screenshots when shaking the device and also want this to work when a UIAlertView is visible.
The problem is that the MotionBegan and MotionEnded-methods are not called. I have tried subclassing UIWindow and UIAlertView and overriding the methods in there, but still nothing gets called.

Am I missing something here?

I enable shake gestures by calling

```
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit = true;
```

in AppDelegate.cs.

And it all works perfectly when there is no UIAlertView visible.

What view responds to shake gestures when an UIAlertView is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend not using `UIAlertView`.

- First it is deprecated in iOS9
- Second it is a really *messed* `UIView`. Apple does not support subclassing it and things goes really sideways when trying to `ResignFirstResponder` so you can receive events. Along with a number of other things about it that are strange, no wonder Apple deprecated it.

Use `UIAlertController` instead, it is available in iOS8/9/10 and acts like a proper `UIViewController` and looks like the old alerts when used with `UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert` style and you will not have any problems with `MotionBegan/MotionEnded` when using it.

**So** you can either override `MotionBegan/MotionEnded` on each of `UIViewController`:

```
public override void MotionBegan(UIEventSubtype motion, UIEvent evt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MotionBegin");
    base.MotionBegan(motion, evt);
}

public override void MotionEnded(UIEventSubtype motion, UIEvent evt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MotionEnded");
    base.MotionEnded(motion, evt);
}
```

**Or** create your own UIWindow subclass and and thus you will get globally motion events (you can just post (`PostNotificationName`) via notification center if other areas of your app need to respond to the motion events.

```
public class ShakeWindow : UIWindow
{
    public ShakeWindow() : base() { }

    public ShakeWindow(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    public override void MotionBegan(UIEventSubtype motion, UIEvent evt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window MotionBegin");
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("ShakeMe", this);
        base.MotionBegan(motion, evt);
    }

    public override void MotionEnded(UIEventSubtype motion, UIEvent evt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window MotionEnded");
        base.MotionEnded(motion, evt);
    }
}
```

`UIAlertController` Example using `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
var button2 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
button2.SetTitle("Alert 2", UIControlState.Normal);
button2.Frame = new CGRect(20, 60, 100, 40);
button2.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var alert2 = UIAlertController.Create("StackOverflow", "Shake me now", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("ShakeMe"), (obj) => 
    {
        alert2?.DismissViewController(true, null);
    });
    alert2.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (UIAlertAction obj) =>
    {
        alert2.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }));
    PresentViewControllerAsync(alert2, true);
};
Add(button2);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick reply. I will use a UIAlertController instead. The reason for using UIAlertViews is that some of the users still have iOS 7 and thus won't be able to display UIAlerViewControllers. But since this screenshot-feature only is for internal testing purposes I'll just check the OS version when displaying alerts. Should have implemented UIAlertViewControllers anyway :-)

Comment: @Hypo : If you end up having to support alerts on iOS7(+) I would create a custom `UIViewController` and reproduce the Alert-look, not really much to it... good luck and happy Xammie coding...